# How to find a number from its 3 digit combinations?

Tags: algorithm, search, language-agnostic, logic, combinations

If there is a 8 digit number 65478209 (the digits in the number can repeat) and given the combinations are always in the order of the number, then if all combinations 8c3 = 56 combinations are given then what will be the shortest solution to find out the number(s) ?

An example scenario could be a bank login where user need to enter 3 random digits of their code like 3rd, 5th and 6th, where this is one of the 8c3 combination. So if all 8c3 combinations are given then what will be the solution/logic to find the number? (or first number if there are more numbers as a solution)

For problem solving in programming language,  the input will an array of 56 3 digit combinations, and we have to find the code which is "65478209" or whatever.

Comment: This is actually really interesting. It's kind of like a Sudoku solver. My first thought without coding anything is to make a bunch of arrays. Do you **know** that digits will not be repeated? non-repeating digits makes it a lot easier.

Comment: @goodguy5, yes the digits can be repeated. Its alot interesting to solve this, but I am not sure how to target the community and couldnt find solutions online. Would be good if you guys could pop in input

Answer (score 2):

How about using permutation? I write the simple code in c++ style. Check it.

```
int k = 3;
string digit = "65478209";
int digitLen = digit.length();

int* indexArr = new int[digitLen];
for(int i=0; i < digitLen; i++) indexArr[i] = i;

do
{
    bool isInOrder=true;
    string ret = "";
    for(int i=1; i < k; i++) if(indexArr[i] < indexArr[i-1])
    {
        isInOrder = false;
        break;
    }
    if(!(isInOrder)) continue;

    for(int i=0; i < k; i++) ret += digit[indexArr[i]];
} while(next_permutation(indexArr, indexArr+digitLen));

delete indexArr;
```

## Edit

here is my solution.

```
vector<string> combinations;
set<int> includedDigit;
vector<int> referCnt;

// Get reference count from all precedences
for(int i=0; i < combinations.size(); i++)
{
    string e = combinations[i];
    for(int j=0; j < k-1; j++)
    {
        includedDigit.insert(e.at(j) - '0');
        for(int l=j+1; l < k; l++)
        {
            int curDigit = e.at(l) - '0';
            referCnt.push_back(curDigit);
        }
    }
}

// Sorting reference counts with digit
vector<pair<int,int>> ret;
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int digitCnt = count(referCnt.begin(), referCnt.end(), i);
    if(digitCnt == 0 && includedDigit.find(i) != includedDigit.end()) ret.push_back(make_pair(1, i));
    else if(digitCnt != 0) ret.push_back(make_pair(digitCnt, i));
}
sort(ret.begin(), ret.end());

// Print the result
for(auto it=ret.begin(); it != ret.end(); it++)
{
    pair<int,int> val = *it;
    cout << val.second;
}
```

It works although I think it can be shorten. In addition, if original digit is not kind of permutation, it should be more complex.

Comment: As you know, converting string to int is simple. `std::stoi(str)`

Comment: I mean, the input will an array of 56 3 digit combinations, and we have to find the code which is "65478209".

Comment: Okay. I misunderstood. Then, we have to make map for constructing relation information about digits. I will edit post

Comment: I added the solution. Please check it.

Comment: @stak, I mean the "logic" is there. You should be able to convert the language. Did you try to use this example to write it in Java? If so, what was your hangup? Or do you just want the "read-to-go" code given to you?

Comment: @goodguy5, I am not too familiar with C++ syntax, Finding difficulty to conver to Java or C#. I can see there are different datasets and operators. Could someone at least comment on steps or provide in one of the above languages. Also I am not sure if this aims for repeated digits in the given number.

Comment: @stak, There is little difference between C++ and C# or Java. For example `pair<int,int>` can be easily changed to `HashMap<Integer,Integer>` in Java. `count` and `sort` are also general function you know. Anyway, I said this code is needed to modify for repeated digits. I just propose initial and easier version for this problem as start point. However, you can get final result you want from this solution. Why don't you consider deeply?

Comment: @stack, there is `Vector` class in Java [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html). cout is used for standard output stream, which is equivalent for `System.out.print()`. `val.second` indicates the second value of `pair<int,int>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
k = 3
```

The following recursive algorithm picks all of the k-element combinations from an ordered set:

1. Choose `i` as first element.
2. Combine `i` with each of the combinations of `k-1` elements chosen recursively from the set of elements larger than `i`.
3. Iterate the above for each `i` in the set.